# Getting "org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 null" on restTemplate.postForObject request to Graphdb

Tags: graphdb

```
**Code:**

 String path = String.format("/%s/uploadRuleSet", REST_REPO_PATH);
        String repoUrl = getRepositoryManager().getLocation().toString();
        URI uri = new URIBuilder(repoUrl + path).build();
        InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("repoconfig/ccs-ruleset.pie");
        ByteArrayResource byteResource = new ByteArrayResource(IOUtils.toString(stream, UTF_8).getBytes(UTF_8)) {
            @Override
            public String getFilename() {
                return "ccs-ruleset.pie";
            }
        };

        MultiValueMap<String, Object> multipartMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        multipartMap.add("ruleset", byteResource);

        logger.info("Uploading ruleset to: {}", uri);
        response = rest.postForObject(uri, multipartMap, RulesetResponse.class);
```

**At  rest.postForObject(uri, multipartMap, RulesetResponse.class);
When it is trying to upload the ruleset,I get the Following stack trace:**

Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 null
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:97) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:730) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:688) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:662) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]

**I checked the logs in the graphdb:**

[DEBUG] 2020-04-01 02:48:45,716 [http-nio-7200-exec-2 | o.e.r.h.s.ProtocolUtil] Acceptable formats: text/csv;q=0.8, application/sparql-results+json;q=0.8, application/json;q=0.8, application/sparql-results+xml;q=0.8, application/xml;q=0.8, text/tab-separated-values;q=0.8, application/x-binary-rdf-results-table
[INFO ] 2020-04-01 02:48:45,723 [http-nio-7200-exec-2 | o.e.r.h.s.r.TupleQueryResultView] Request for query 3392903 is finished
[INFO ] 2020-04-01 02:58:52,742 [http-nio-7200-exec-4 | c.o.t.r.RuleCompilerBase] Current file: /opt/graphdb/graphdb-free-8.9.0/work/tmp/graphdb6671553462073041570/work/Tomcat/localhost/ROOT/ccs-ruleset1585735132740.pie
**[INFO ] 2020-04-01 02:58:52,762 [http-nio-7200-exec-4 | c.o.t.r.RuleCompilerBase] Compiled: '/opt/graphdb/graphdb-free-8.9.0/work/tmp/graphdb6671553462073041570/work/Tomcat/localhost/ROOT/ccs-ruleset1585735132740.pie'**
[DEBUG] 2020-04-01 02:59:11,593 [http-nio-7200-exec-5 | o.e.r.h.s.ProtocolUtil] Acceptable formats: text/csv;q=0.8, application/sparql-results+json;q=0.8, application/json;q=0.8, application/sparql-results+xml;q=0.8, application/xml;q=0.8, text/tab-separated-values;q=0.8, application/x-binary-rdf-results-table
[INFO ] 2020-04-01 02:59:11,593 [http-nio-7200-exec-5 | o.e.r.h.s.r.TupleQueryResultView] Request for query 3392903 is finished

**GraphDB logs seems to indicate that there weren't any issues.
But on the client side I get the HttpServerErrorException : 500 log.
Not able to figure out what exactly the issue is...**

Answer (score 0):

Returned result from GraphDB is UploadRuleSetResult, not RulesetResponse. You're giving invalid responseType to postForObject method. Changing the type will solve the issue.

Comment: RulesetResponse is a userdefined class in our project.

public class RulesetResponse {
    private boolean success;
    private String errorMessage;
    private String fileLocation;
  /** setter and getter methods**/
  }
 
UploadRuleSetResult, what do I define this as?
 
Code works totally fine without any exception in RHEL 7.6 instance of GraphDB, the problem arises when we use RHEL 7.7 instance of the graphdb.

Comment: I've created test with defined RulesetResponse class with same fields as your user defined and it works. As I couldn't see the repoUrl and REST_REPO_PATH fields. The API endpoint is 'protocol://host:port/rest/repositories/uploadRuleSet'

Comment: The only difference is that I'm testing against the last version of GDB, where Spring Version is 5.1.14.